# Error building a SQL query while trying to get order by a day for a period of week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an ASP.NET Core application, through controller endpoint I pass `@by` and `@period` string values to the SQL query.

- `@by` takes one of the following values: day, week
- `@period` takes one of the following values: week, month, year

When the `@period` is month or year, then `@by` is a week, else it's a day.

I have the following working query when the `@period` is a month or a year:

```
SELECT
    l.region_id AS region_id,
    'Region ' + r.region_desc AS region_name,
    MIN(DATEADD(D, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, s.pos_date) - 1), s.pos_date)) AS date_pos,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MIN(DATEADD(D, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, s.pos_date) - 1), s.pos_date)), 107) AS display_date_pos
FROM 
    incent_summary s 
INNER JOIN 
    location l ON s.store_num = l.store_num
INNER JOIN
    region r ON l.region_id = r.region_id
WHERE 
    s.pos_date >= DATEADD(day, @period , CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
    AND s.pos_date <= GETDATE()
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART (@by, s.pos_date), 
    l.region_id, r.region_desc
ORDER BY 
    DATEPART (@by, pos_date),
    l.region_id, r.region_desc
```

The issue is when the `@period` is a week, `@by` is day, and the statement

```
 MIN(DATEADD(D, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, s.pos_date) - 1), s.pos_date)) AS date_pos
```

returns the same day for all the 7 days.

Sample output when `@period = year` and `@by = week`:

```
region_id   region_name  date_pos                   display_date_pos
---------------------------------------------------------------------
34          Region 43    2019-12-29 00:00:00.000    Dec 29, 2019
50          Region 22    2019-12-29 00:00:00.000    Dec 29, 2019
34          Region 43    2020-01-05 00:00:00.000    Jan 05, 2020
50          Region 22    2020-01-05 00:00:00.000    Jan 05, 2020
34          Region 43    2020-01-12 00:00:00.000    Jan 12, 2020
50          Region 22    2020-01-12 00:00:00.000    Jan 12, 2020
34          Region 43    2020-01-19 00:00:00.000    Jan 19, 2020
50          Region 22    2020-01-19 00:00:00.000    Jan 19, 2020
34          Region 43    2020-01-26 00:00:00.000    Jan 26, 2020
50          Region 22    2020-01-26 00:00:00.000    Jan 26, 2020
```

Sample output when `@period = week and @by = day`:

```
region_id   region_name  date_pos                   display_date_pos
--------------------------------------------------------------------
34          Region 43    2020-07-12 00:00:00.000    Jul 12, 2020
50          Region 22    2020-07-12 00:00:00.000    Jul 12, 2020
34          Region 43    2020-07-12 00:00:00.000    Jul 12, 2020
50          Region 22    2020-07-12 00:00:00.000    Jul 12, 2020
34          Region 43    2020-07-19 00:00:00.000    Jul 19, 2020
50          Region 22    2020-07-19 00:00:00.000    Jul 19, 2020
34          Region 43    2020-07-19 00:00:00.000    Jul 19, 2020
50          Region 22    2020-07-19 00:00:00.000    Jul 19, 2020
34          Region 43    2020-07-19 00:00:00.000    Jul 19, 2020
50          Region 22    2020-07-19 00:00:00.000    Jul 19, 2020
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: MS SQL Server it is

Comment: @Sameer can you provide some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: @sacse added sample output

Comment: Thanks, @Sameer. what should be the expected output? are those actual outputs or expected outputs?

Comment: So I'm not sure how this statement is working if `@period` is a string: `s.pos_date >= DATEADD(day, @period , CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  DATEADD(D, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, s.pos_date) - 1), s.pos_date)
```

Will always return the first day of the week because the logic is: "subtract from my date the number of days from sunday and add 1."

```
Sunday: 1 - 1 + 1 = 1 = Sunday 
Monday: 2 - 2 + 1 = 1 = Sunday
.
.
.
Saturday: 7 - 7 + 1 = Sunday
```

That's fine when you want the first Sunday of the year/month/whatever.  But the first sunday of every week is always... sunday.  But in this case you really just need to take the `MIN(s.pos_date)` if `@period` is week.

There's probably some crazy way to do this in a single statement using quaternions or something else super mathy, but it's easiest to just use a case statement:

```
MIN
  (
    CASE
      WHEN '@by' = 'day' THEN s.pos_date
      ELSE DATEADD(D, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, s.pos_date) - 1), s.pos_date)
    END
  )
```

I'm not a C# programmer so I can't tell you the exact way to make sure the string `DAY` is passed to the query as `"DAY"` but I'm sure you can handle that part.

**ALSO IMPORTANT** The datepart "day" is day of month, so if you're going to possibly have a span greater than one month (but under a year), use `dayofyear`.